# Renaming next's output folder from "_next" to "next"

Tags: next.js

I came across use-case today where I was trying to get my nextjs app working in android webview, unfortunately android doesn't resolve paths that begin with `_next` and most of my chunk files are under `_next/static` when I build my app.

Is there a way to to rename this folder from `_next` to `next` or anything else?
This issue will give extra context about how android works in this regard [Android project is not resolving any static assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156104/android-project-is-not-resolving-any-static-assets/59158114#59158114)

Comment: there are many places with `_next` in the next.js codebase, so it looks like it's not supposed to be configured.

Comment: Seems like next.js what us to use their own setup, not giving us option on how we use it.

Answer (score 1):

I handled this issue via Nginx Routing.

What i assumed while making this Nginx Routing is that every file will have unique hash and file name combination.

This is the snippet of code of Nginx Routing which i used.

```
location /static/ {
    try_files $uri @server1;
}
location @server1{
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1$uri;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;
    error_page 404 = @server2;
}

location @server2{
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2$uri;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;
    error_page 404 = @server3;
}

location @server3{
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.3$uri;
}
```

What the above code does is, whenever Nginx encounters /_next/ it will first try that URL with @server1, if that Server responds with 404, the Nginx then transfers the request to @server2 as mentioned in error_page param.

This example works like:
`try_files $uri @server1 @server2 @server3`

This worked for me as i had 2 apps which were developed on Next and both has _next route.

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Nice, although in my case I need it to generate output with rename folder i.e. no access to server overwrites